# Problems of convergence of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I was really confused about the following problems of topology. Thank you in advance for any help.

If $A$ and $B$(not $\emptyset$) are both subsets of a set $X$, and they do not intersect. Suppose the topology $\Gamma$ consists $X$,$\emptyset$ and all subsets of $X$ which contain $A$. Is there a possibility for a sequence in $B$ that the limit point is not in $B$?

Thank you again!

Comment: For the first question: if $x \notin B$ is a limit of a sequence in $B$, consider the set $X \setminus B$. It is open (why?) and contains $x$. Can you finish? For the second question, note that in this case all sets $\{y\}$ for $y \in X$ are open (why?). Can you interpret what it means that a sequence converges to $x \in X$, noting that $\{x\}$ is open?

Comment: A sequence is never finite (it's a function with infinite domain), you probably mean that the range is finite? In this case we can ecen say the sequence is eventually constant which is even stronger than that.

Comment: @maiyuqiang The first one is fine. For the second one, $X$ has the discrete topology, since $A = \emptyset$ and the topology on $X$ consists of $\emptyset$ and all subsets of $X$ that contain $A$. So all singletons are open, hence, as you noted, any convergent sequence is eventually constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So $A \cap B = \emptyset$ are two non-empty subsets of a set $X$ and we consider $\tau_A$, the included set topology wrt $A$ on $X$.

If $(b_n)_n$ is a sequence in $B$, that converges to $x \in X$, then a basic neighbourhood of $x$ looks like $A \cup \{x\}$ and must contain almost all terms of the sequence. It's clear that this only happens if almost all $b_n = x$ already (as $A$ and $B$ are disjoint), and in particular $x \in B$. So the only sequences from $B$ that converge at all are those that are eventually constant.

If $A=\emptyset$ then $\tau_A = \mathscr{P}(X)$ the discrete topology and the same remark holds. In fact, in that case, *any* sequence $(x_n)_n$ can only converge to $x$ iff $x_n =x$ for almost all $n$.

In the general case (that we started with), if we have any sequence $(a_n)_n$ from $A$ then for any $x \in X$, $a_n \to x$, again as a basic neighbourhood of $x$ always contains all of $A$ so the whole sequence.

Comment: @maiyuqiang because, as I argued, the sequence is eventually constant : $\exists N \forall n \ge N: x_n = x$ which implies that the set of values is $\{x_1,\ldots, x_N\}$, so finite.